# QGraphicsPixmapItem.setScale set pixel boundaries at inconsistant positions

Tags: python, c++, qt, pyqt

I want to zoom on an image using `QGraphicsPixmapItem.setScale`. However the scaling starts being very shaky at high magnification levels, i.e. when only a few pixels fill the window. I observe the same phenomenon in PyQt 4.8.7 and 5.6.0, on Windows 10 as well as Ubuntu 16.10. EDIT: tested on the more recent PyQt 5.10, with the same outcome. EDIT: tested in plain C++ Qt as well, see below.

Here is an example where the scaling factor being controlled by the mouse wheel.

```python
import numpy as np
try:
    from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt, QRectF
    from PyQt5.QtGui import QImage, QPixmap
    from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QGraphicsScene, QGraphicsView, QMainWindow
    qt_ver = 5
except:
    from PyQt4.QtCore import Qt, QRectF
    from PyQt4.QtGui import QImage, QPixmap
    from PyQt4.QtGui import QApplication, QGraphicsScene, QGraphicsView, QMainWindow
    qt_ver = 4

app = QApplication([])


class MyGraphicsView(QGraphicsView):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.scene = QGraphicsScene(QRectF())
        self.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOff)
        self.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOff)
        self.setScene(self.scene)
        im = np.random.randint(255, size=(100, 100, 3), dtype=np.uint8)
        qim = QImage(im, 100, 100, QImage.Format_RGB888)
        pix = QPixmap.fromImage(qim)
        self.pixi = self.scene.addPixmap(pix)
        self.pixi.setOffset(-50, -50)
        self.zoom = 0

    def wheelEvent(self, event):
        if qt_ver == 5:
          delta = event.angleDelta().y()
        else:
          delta = event.delta()
        if delta > 0:
            self.zoom += 1
        elif delta < 0:
            self.zoom -= 1
        self.pixi.setScale(np.exp(self.zoom * 0.1))


window = QMainWindow()
window.setGeometry(100, 100, 900, 900)
view = MyGraphicsView(window)
window.setCentralWidget(view)
window.show()
app.exec()
```

It looks like scaling is suffering from rounding issues. Am I doing something wrong?

Same behavior in C++, this is not a PyQt/python issue. I am wondering if that could be due to a discretization effect due to the poor precision of `float32`? That could be hard to fix.

```c++
# include <cstdint>
# include <cmath>
# include <random>
# include <vector>

# include <QApplication>
# include <QGraphicsPixmapItem>
# include <QGraphicsView>
# include <QImage>
# include <QMainWindow>
# include <QPixmap>
# include <QWheelEvent>
# include <QWidget>

class MyGraphicsView
        : public QGraphicsView
{
private:
    int _zoom = 0;
    std::vector<std::uint8_t> _im_data;
    QGraphicsScene * _scene = nullptr;
    QPixmap _pix;
    QGraphicsPixmapItem * _pixi = nullptr;

public:
    MyGraphicsView(QWidget * parent)
        : QGraphicsView(parent)
    {
        _scene = new QGraphicsScene(QRectF(), this);
        this->setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(Qt::ScrollBarAlwaysOff);
        this->setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(Qt::ScrollBarAlwaysOff);
        this->setScene(_scene);
        _im_data.resize(100 * 100 * 3);
        std::random_device rd;
        std::mt19937 mt(rd());
        std::uniform_int_distribution<> distr(0, std::numeric_limits<std::uint8_t>::max());
        for (auto & e: _im_data) e = std::uint8_t(distr(mt));
        auto im = QImage(_im_data.data(), 100, 100, QImage::Format_RGB888);
        _pix = QPixmap::fromImage(std::move(im));
        _pixi = _scene->addPixmap(_pix);
        _pixi->setOffset(-50, -50);
    }
    void wheelEvent(QWheelEvent *event) override
    {
        auto delta = event->angleDelta().y();
        if (delta > 0)
            ++_zoom;
        else if (delta < 0)
            --_zoom;
        _pixi->setScale(std::exp(_zoom * 0.1));
    }
};


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);

    auto window = new QMainWindow();
    window->setGeometry(100, 100, 900, 900);
    auto view = new MyGraphicsView(window);
    window->setCentralWidget(view);
    window->show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

**EDIT**

Might be a bug. I filed [QTBUG-66310](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-66310).

Comment: You mean this little movement that is given? Do you want the center of the image always be the center of the window? That flickering occurs on all scales but it is only noticeable when you scale it many times.

Comment: @eyllanesc Yes, I would like the image center to remain at the window center. In any case I would expect the scaling to have a fixed fixed point; instead it is jumping around rather disgracefully as scaling changes. I must say that I tried to add a `self.centerOn(0, 0)` after scaling that did not affect the outcome.

Comment: Checking the [docs](http://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/qgraphicspixmapitem.html#details) I found the following: *You can set the pixmap's transformation mode by calling setTransformationMode(). By default, Qt::FastTransformation is used, which provides fast, non-smooth scaling. Qt::SmoothTransformation enables QPainter::SmoothPixmapTransform on the painter, and the quality depends on the platform and viewport. **The result is usually not as good as calling QPixmap::scale() directly.** Call transformationMode() to get the current transformation mode for the item.*

Comment: @eyllanesc Thanks. That's disappointing. Using `SmoothPixmapTransform` gets rid of the tremor but smoothes out pixels by bylinear interpolation, which I don't want. Calling `QPixmap::scale` resizes the entire pixmap -- not something I want to do with zoom factors both extreme and ever changing. It seems I am stuck...